# Configure .NET CLR RAM usage

Tags: .net, clr, ram

Is there a method of configuring the .NET CLR RAM usage on my machine?

Suppose I have 64GB of RAM and I want to limit it to 4GB?  It this possible?

**Edit** - The root of the problem is that I have a 64-bit application that runs fine on a 64bit - 4GB machine but when run on a 64bit - 64GB machine it fails (stops dead in it's tracks when allocating memory).  I'm thinking memory fragmentation is the cause as the application attempts to allocate up to 8GB chunks if there is enough RAM available otherwise it breaks the allocations down to much smaller chunks.  So I would have to configure the application to always use small chunks?

Comment: this might be abetter question for serverfault

Answer (score 2):

Have at look at the machine.config file in

%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework[version]\CONFIG

The memoryLimit attribute controls the percentage of physical memory that a process is allowed to consume. I know this is not exactly what you are looking for but the closest I could find.

Comment: Where exactly does the memoryLimit attribute go?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using [PublicDomain](http://www.codeplex.com/publicdomain). It is a library that exposes a lot of lower level capabilities, such as spawning processes with memory limits. There is actually a CodeProject article that describes how to do exactly that with PublicDomain:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/Setting_Max_Memory_Limit.aspx